# Proper usage of an old OCXO

Tags: oscillator

I had some legacy equipment that was no longer needed, so before getting rid of it I opened it up to remove any hardware I might later have use for.

Inside I found a nice Wenzel 10 MHz OCXO:
[image: Wenzel OCXO]

The oscillator has no info online, but I called Wenzel and they were able to dig up a 1-page datasheet:
[image: OCXO datasheet]

I tested it and it works wonderfully. I manually steered the frequency to our master clock reference, by tweaking a small voltage applied to pin 6 (Electrical Tuning). I didn't use pin 5 (V Reference) for anything.

My questions are:

**1**. What is the purpose of pin 5 (V Reference). Should it be connected to ground of the +/- 5 VDC tuning voltage?

*In my testing I needed to supply a negative voltage, approx -1 VDC, to achieve a near zero rate between the OCXO and our master clock. But I didn't bother with pin 5 and it still worked.*

---

<edit: **#2** below was answered sufficiently by Peter in the comments>

**2**. There is a hole on one side of the oscillator. And far inside the hole is a tiny screw. The hole is threaded. So, I think the hole is dual purpose: to provide access to the screw (which must be for manual frequency tuning); and provide a mounting option. I just need confirmation that this is correct.

[image: hole in OCXO]

Thanks

Comment: A wild guess (so am not attempting an answer): **Vref** may be a return path for the **Electrical tuning** voltage, in an attempt to isolate DC supply voltage from tuning voltage. If so, it ought to be similar to **ground**.

Comment: If the hole you mention is on the end opposite the connectors, the drawing indicates that is provides access to a tuning adjustment, and should normally have a "seal screw" installed to prevent tampering, and to keep out contaminants.  I wouldn't use it for mounting.

Comment: @PeterBennett So it does! Thanks, I missed that. Interesting that the group that built the instrument from which I got this part, didn't bother to install a seal screw.

Comment: Or someone adjusted it and forgot to re-install it during maintenance.

Comment: Looks like it would make a good coffee mug warmer.

Comment: @pericynthion it actually stays quite cool - it warms a little but I'm sure it is well insulated to maintain thermal regularity. It's also much lighter than one might expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vref pin is the voltage with which the electrical tuning voltage is in reference to.  So if you were applying a voltage to the tuning pin...well, no, you probably weren't.  You'd need to connect Vref to the ground with which that voltage is in reference to for there to be a tuning voltage present.

Without the complete datasheet, it's impossible to be sure if it is safe to leave either of these pins floating.  I would short them to each other if unused, and possibly ground them as well, though it is unlikely that is necessary.  As the tuning voltage is ±5V, that would mean that a  potential of 0V (like if pins 5 and 6 were shorted) is the 'neutral' or 'center' of the tuning range.  From here, pin 6 can vary between -5V and 5V, pulling the frequency 500ppb faster or slower.

Of course, all the ***really*** interesting things you might use that fine bit of kit for would probably benefit from the ability to use those pins.

That thing has 5 ***ppb*** (parts per billion, aka \$10^{-9}\$) stability, which even today is excellent.  You'd be hard pressed to find a similarly performing OCXO today for less than $100.  Great find!   If you want a good idea of all the cool stuff you could potentially use it for, just skim (at random, really) some of the recent [Time-Nuts mailinglist archives](https://www.febo.com/pipermail/time-nuts/).  Sister list to my bros, **Volt-Nuts**, these are other like-minded individuals with a passion for precision.  I admit the format is a bit dated (mailing list instead of a proper forum) but the archives work almost as well.

Or, if this idea appeals to you, you could always just write the mailing list about your new OXCO - I'm sure they'd be thrilled to help you figure out a project both interesting to you,  within the realm of possibility to achieve (some suggestions in this kind of precision metrology hobby can have...unrealistic ideas about personal income investment), and perfectly suited to your OXCO.

Or, if you aren't *that* interested, you might consider putting it on ebay.  These things retain their value, you'd get some dosh for it certainly.  But if you are interested in this sort of thing, by all means, build something cool with it.  Personally, I think its a great hobby - and one that is easy or as challenging as you make it.

Regardless, have fun.  Good call on looking through that old gear before tossing it.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by; "So if you were applying a voltage to the tuning pin...well, no, you probably weren't". As I wrote in my post, that is exactly what I was doing. By supplying a small voltage to the tuning pin, I was able to steer the frequency to maintain syntonization with our master clock. In my case, a small negative voltage was needed. I could easily see the rate change as I slowly tuned the applied tuning voltage. I manually tied the ground of my tuning voltage to case ground during my tests, but left the ref pin floating.

Comment: Follow up question: If Vref is not internally tied to ground, does this suggest that I could apply 5 V to Vref, and then tune from 0-10 V? This would allow me to no longer require a negative supply.

Comment: @peufeu Actually, I couldn't be more happy with it myself. I wouldn't put it on eBay. I plan to use it. Also, I couldn't put it on eBay even if I wanted to. I got it from lab equipment at work.

Comment: Also, I love the suggestion and reference to the mailing list (+1) Thanks for that. As it happens, I have an application already in mind for it. I knew what I was going to do with it as soon as I saw it. And I need the tuning pins; the stability and tuning pins are why it's useful to me. I'm in development of highly stable satellite time transfer.